# How to update the wurfl resource of Zend_Http_UserAgent

Tags: php, zend-framework, wurfl

i'm using Wurfl-adapter of Zend_Http_UserAgent as described here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html

Do I need to update the wurfl xml-file manually from time to time or does Wurfl update itself automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to update it manually from time to time.